# What is the meaning of 奴 this poem from 红楼梦？

Tags: meaning-in-context

Poetry is never easy to understand. 奴 is used twice in this poem. I think this 奴 means I or me, in a sense of 'me, this poor slave'.

怪**奴**底事倍伤神？半为怜春半恼春。
怜春忽至恼忽去，至又无言去不闻。

昨宵庭外悲歌发，知是花魂与鸟魂。
花魂鸟魂总难留，鸟自无言花自羞。

愿**奴**胁下生双翼，随花飞落天尽头。
天尽头，何处有香丘？

Comment: 一般的女性第一人称谦称罢了，我所读过的版本也作“侬”

Comment: 我读的有：尔今死去侬收葬，未卜侬身何日丧？

Comment: Hey, Pedroski, long time no see - welcome back.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of 谦称 of a woman in ancient China, there are others of course

> 妾 *or* 妾身 *or* 奴婢 *for* you being the wife
>
> 奴 *or* 奴家 *for* you being the wife *or* general cases
>
> 小女子 *for* general cases
>
> 老身 *for* older ladies

And for men of course, their 谦称 could be

> 小人 *for* you being the servant
>
> 鄙人 *for* general but unofficial use
>
> 在下 *for* you being in a relatively lower social hierarchy
>
> 晚生 if you are younger to your friend
>
> 不才 *for* proposing suggestions
>
> 不肖 *for* referring yourself with respect to your older relatives
>
> 愚弟 *or* 愚兄 *for* closer relationship